# Get the current UIView's ID objective-c iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiwindow

How can I get the current `UIView`'s ID so that I can use it later without using an `IBOutlet`?

I would like to add an image over the top of my app but I'm switching views frequently and would like to be able to add the image to the current view because it would show up in my second view

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using an IBOutlet?

Comment: @ChaseJohnson I would like to add an image over the top of my app but I'm switching views frequently and would like to be able to add the image to the current view because it would show up in my second view.

Comment: Please see my edited answer for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access a UIView by ID in the way that you can on Android devices. IBOutlets are the equivalent for connecting graphical layouts to code.

Based in your comment, the appropriate thing for you to do is to be adding the overlay view at a higher level in the view hierarchy. If you have two views that could be displayed at any given time, and you want to make sure you can cover either of them regardless of which is in place, add your overlay view to the superview of those two. This works all the way up to using the UIWindow object that your App Delegate has, which will let you overlay on top of everything (this is essentially how UIAlertViews work, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

You could set the UIView's tag attribute. Then you can reference it from the superview with

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
```